# JMeter: While sending post request data value with quote Jmeter is adding escape character during sending request to server

Tags: regex, jmeter, session-cookies, correlation, blazemeter

We want to post some data value with quotes, which is being captured using correlation

String:
Request_UserKey=**"==paddas"**

correlation regex used to extract value 
UserKey="(.*?)"
we capture value without quotes with this regexp, captured value is ==paddas

but we need to pass value with quotes so we concatenate quote with correlated value and stored in temp variable.
temp value is "==paddas"

Now when when we are sending temp value in post request then value is going like UserKey="\"==paddas"\" but we want to send data like this UserKey="==paddas"

JMeter adding extra \" before quote so please help how to send correct value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your speaking of HTTP POST request, quotes are not allowed.
You have to urlencode the data.

For example, `"blah"` is gonna be encoded `%22blah%22`.

Look for "urlencode online" in your favorite search engine.